# Choice of analysis for a bipolar scale in which the two extremes indicate negative responses and the neutral response indicates a positive response

Tags: modeling, likert

I am attempting to perform an analysis of a bipolar scale response to a question such as the one below:

How much detail did the textbook provide?

1. Too little detail
2. Somewhat too little detail
3. Just the right amount of detail
4. Somewhat too much detail
5. Too much detail

Is there a problem using standard linear regression for an outcome like this. Putting to the side the issue of ordinality vs continuity in the response variable, does the strange ordering of the response mean that the results of a regression would be uninterpretable. For instance let's say I obtain a beta weight of 1, suggesting that the IV of interest increases the response by 1 for each unit of the IV, is this useful in any sense given that the optimal response for evaluation purposes lies midway through the scale rather than at the end?

Is there a method for assessing this format of question, while including covariates in the model, as in multiple regression?

Thanks.

Comment: I  wanted that  you affirm scoring of 1to 5 . you said it was a possibility. Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: I want  you to know that likert scale does not/can not work  the way you  wish it to implemented. The two extremes can not be negative ( or positive).

Comment: Not that this is a sufficient argument, but in most studies I have seen that make use of likert scales they are treated as either or ordinal or continuous. I see in a response to another question Frank Harrell has suggested the use of proportional odds models for these sorts of outcomes. Are you suggesting that the data should be treated as nominal (i.e. as discrete categories with no order relation)? I don't see why I need to edit the question.

Comment: I can't log in to chat right now. Thanks though. I see why there is confusion. I meant negative in the sense of "a negative evaluation". Not in the sense of negative numbers. Incidentally, if you are talking about negative numbers then your statement that "the two extremes cannot be negative" is incorrect. I don't think there is any rule stopping someone from creating, for example, a 5 point scale with the following values assigned to each response in order: -5, -4, -3, -2, -1. If there is, do you have an argument to support what you are claiming?

Comment: I see this as an ordered scale. There are the usual questions about whether and how far ordered scales can be taken literally (i.e. numerically!) which you set aside, but it looks standard to me.

Comment: @NickCox yes, the question of whether the item has a valid ordinal relation is one I can't answer with my data. The format of the question has thrown me a bit, in that the midpoint seems to represent an optimal evaluation, if that makes sense. Normally, I am used to items that are scaled along the lines of 1 = level of detail was poor TO 5 = level of detail was excellent.

Comment: Would it help to score it 2, 1, 0, 1, 2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: It would help if the downvoters explained what is wrong here. It seems a reasonable question to me.

Comment: I do not think that scoring  pattern should be changed as suggested by you if the  question does not require an edit.

Comment: Much of the discussion here is mysterious. One test of an ordinal scale is that you shuffle the categories and ask someone to put them back in order. This ordinal scale seems fine to me. Many other ordinal scales are similar, e.g. strongly agree to strongly disagree. If it is wished to  recode so that 1 and 5 are grouped and 2 and 4 are grouped, leaving 3, to produce a scale of "strength of approval" that's a different reduction of the data. It's up to the researcher (the OP) to decide what is wanted. I can't see that it helps just to assert that one scale is wrong or should not be used.

Comment: @NickCox agreed. I think the approach you have laid out is sensible and I have decided to present the results seperately for approval (where the scale is ordered 1 to 3) and for detail (where the scale is ordered 1 to 5). You and mdewey have provided much clarity.